# How to insert the result of a command into the text in vim?

Tags: vim

For instance, `:echo strftime(%c)` will show the current time on the bottom, but how to insert this time string into the text (right after the cursor)?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this is *not* the same question as [Writing a vim function to insert a block of static text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text), however some of the answers still apply.

Comment: See also redirecting into a register: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file/4283053#4283053

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the [expression register, `"=`,](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote=) with [`p` (or `P`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) in normal mode or [`<C-R>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) in insert mode:

In normal mode:
<sub>(`<C-M>` here means <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, or just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>)</sub>

```
"=strftime('%c')<C-M>p
```

In insert mode:
<sub>(`<C-M>` has the same meaning as above, `<C-R>` means <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)</sub>

```
<C-R>=strftime('%c')<C-M>
```

If you want to insert the result of the same expression many times, then you might want to map them onto keys in your `.vimrc`:
<sub>(here the `<C-M>` and `<C-R>` should be typed literally (a sequence of five printable characters—Vim will translate them internally))</sub>

```
:nmap <F2> "=strftime('%c')<C-M>p
:imap <F2> <C-R>=strftime('%c')<C-M>
```

Comment: +1 Off course! The `"=` register. :-/

Comment: to get the value of a vim variable (for example, sessionoptions): `<C-R>=&sessionoptions` -- it even does wildmode tab-completion!

Comment: :put =strftime('%c')<C-M>

Comment: In insert mode, using `<c-r>=` is slow for command which may have a lot of output and also may break indent so that the output text is unreadable. For example, `<c-r>=execute('nmap')`, the output will be written line by line, which is very slow.

Comment: For some reason, this just doesn't work for me. Any ideas why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Here is now to insert from normal mode without creating a new line: `:nmap F2 a<C-r>=strftime('%c')<C-m><C-c>` (For visual mode, use `vmap` and `c` instead of `a`)

Answer (score 117):

`:r!date +\%c`

see `:help :r!`

Note, this is for external commands (they run in your shell), not vim commands.

Comment: `date` is an external command and `!` calls external commands while OP asks for vim commands.

Comment: @eelvex no he didn't. and the ! is a vim, and vi, command. This is the canonical method. Works for many other things as well.

Comment: @Keith: yes `!` is a vi(m) command that calls *external* commands. You may be right OP not wanting to output only vim commands but if (s)he does, `!` will not do.

Comment: You can combine the output of the external command with text you define. For example, the following adds two pound signs and the date of next Tuesday ("## Tuesday, 2020-06-23"): `:exe 'r!date --date="next Tuesday" "+\%A, \%Y-\%m-\%d"' | normal I## `

Comment: @Keith No they **did not**. OP clearly gave an example of a vim command, not a shell command.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to insert the output of a vim *command* (just like stdout in shell, and as opposed to the *return value of a function call* or an *expression*), you have to capture it.  This is accomplished via the `:redir` command, which allows you to redirect vim's equivalent of standard output into a variable, file, register, or other target.

`:redir` is sort of painfully inconvenient to use; I would write a function to encapsulate its functionality in a more convenient way, something like

```
funct! Exec(command)
    redir =>output
    silent exec a:command
    redir END
    return output
endfunct!
```

Once you've declared such a function, you can use the expression register (as explained by Chris Johnsen) to insert the output of a command at the cursor position.  So, from normal mode, hit `:put =Exec('ls')` to insert the list of vim's current buffers.

Be aware that the command will execute in the function namespace, so if you use a global variable you will have to explicitly namespace it by prefixing it with `g:`.  Also note that `Exec()`, as written above, will append a terminating newline to even one-line output.  You might want to add a call to `substitute()` into the function to avoid this.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/vim-how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file/2573054#2573054 for more blathering on about `redir` and a link to a related command.

Comment: This works great. I added a `set paste` command before returning the output and a `set nopaste` after, to avoid the staircase indent when the lines start with blanks. Actually, I wanted to save the value of the current paste option and to return it but I was unable to do it so.

Comment: @JuanLanus The `set nopaste` shouldn't work after `return output`, because the return statement is an exit point out of the function. I've put my solution to this problem as a separate answer on this page.

Comment: `Instead of i^R=Exec('ls')`, try `:put =Exec('ls')`. That should avoid the need to for setpaste.

Answer (score 12):

These commands will insert the output of `strftime("%c")` right where your cursor is:

```
:exe ":normal i" . strftime("%c")
```

and

```
:call feedkeys("i". strftime("%c"))
```

There are other ways to do what you want (like, for example, those on [Mikel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/in-vimhow-to-insert-the-result-of-a-command-into-the-text/8102#8102)).

**Edit**: Even better, for in-place insert, use the `=` register as [Chris Johnsen describes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/in-vimhow-to-insert-the-result-of-a-command-into-the-text/8109#8109)

Comment: How can we pipe vim command output (f.e. output of `echo "foo"`, instead of `strftime("%c")`) to the buffer?

Comment: @trusktr `feedkeys("i"."foo")`

Answer (score 6):

```
:call append(line('.'), strftime("%c"))
```

Will put it on the next line, then you could press `J` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)to join it up to the current position.

Or if you need it all in one command, you could do

```
:call setline(line('.'), getline(line('.')) . strftime("%c"))
```

or

```
:call setline(line('.'), getline(line('.')) . " " . strftime("%c"))
```

depending on whether you want a space inserted before the date or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:put` with the expression register `=`:

```
:put =strftime('%c')
```

This method allows you to make an alternative command to `:echo` called `:InsertExpr` that would insert your expression:

```
command! -nargs=* InsertExpr put =<args>
```

Or to insert commands like `:ls`:

```
command! -nargs=* InsertCmd put =execute('<args>')
```

(Not sure why I can't get q-args to work.)

Usage:

```
:InsertExpr strftime('%c')
:InsertCmd ls
```

Answer (score 4):

Improving @intuited answer to avoid the problem with leading whitespace and growing indent:

```
"Examples:
":call Exec('buffers')
"This will include the output of :buffers into the current buffer.
"
"Also try:
":call Exec('ls')
":call Exec('autocmd')
"
funct! Exec(command)
    redir =>output
    silent exec a:command
    redir END
    let @o = output
    execute "put o"
    return ''
endfunct!
```

This will simply insert at the current location in the file when you `:call Exec('command')` from normal mode. As noted in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/how-to-insert-the-result-of-a-command-into-the-text-in-vim#comment293994_8296), the original (insert-mode) Ctrl+R `=Exec('command')` approach with `Exec(..)` returning a string could be partially corrected by using `set paste`, but doesn't offer an opportunity to put the `set nopaste` anywhere.

The `let @o = output` syntax sets the register `o` to the contents of the variable `output`, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22738310/1143274

The `return ''` line is so that the default return value of `0` doesn't get inserted to the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it. It puts it right after the cursor because it uses `p`.

```
" save previous yank
let reg_save = @@

" save your text to the '@' register
let @@ = strftime('%c')
" paste it after the cursor
exec "normal! p"

" restore previous yank
let @@ = reg_save
```

Answer (score 1):

If you end up mapping it at the end then there is a nicer way.

```
inoremap <expr> <C-f> strftime('%c')
```

This is quite general, just substitude your binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and your function for `strftime('%c')`.